# ¿Cómo resolver el error HTTP 500 en mi sitio web?

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel

¿Por qué me aparece este error?

> Esta página no funciona. La página [www.gns.com.mx](http://www.gns.com.mx) no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora. HTTP ERROR 500

Acabo de subir un sitio web al servidor por medio de FTP. Tengo una función que se encarga de importar datos de un archivo excel (xls) a una base de datos en MySQL. El problema es que cuando le doy clic al botón importar me sale ese error.

Les dejo el código del archivo que importa a la BD:

```
`<?php 

include 'db-connection.php'; //Agregamos la conexión
require 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'; //Agregamos la librería 

    //Variable con el nombre del archivo
$archiveName = 'archive/REPORTS.xls';
    // Cargo la hoja de cálculo
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($archiveName);

    //Asigno la hoja de calculo activa
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    //Obtengo el numero de filas del archivo
$numRows = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();

for ($i = 6; $i <= $numRows; $i++) {

    $idUser = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $date = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('G'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $day = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('H'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $getIn = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('J'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $getOut = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('K'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ivms_info (idUser, date_today, day, get_in, get_out) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connectionString, $sql)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssss', $idUser, $date, $day, $getIn, $getOut);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    } else {
        echo "No existe ningún archivo para importar.";
    }
}

mysqli_close($connectionString);
header('location: admin.php');

?>`
```

En el siguiente bloque es donde mando llamar al archivo:

```
`<a class="nav-link btn-sm px-2 px-lg-1" href="db-import.php">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm-circle btn-sm">
                            <i class="far fa-file-excel"></i>
                        </button>
                    </a>`
```

Esto me funciona localmente, pero cuando lo subí al servidor no funcionó.

Espero y me puedan ayudar, gracias!!

Comment: Revisa el log de errores de tu servidor remoto, puede que te faltan archivos o librerías y que por eso no esté funcionando en ese contexto.

Comment: Echa un ojo al significado de los códigos HTTP aquí: https://codigoshttp.com
Tu error es el siguiente: https://codigoshttp.com/500/

Comment: Gracias amigos, lo resolví checando el log de errores. Era una extensión ZIP que me faltaba añadir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo resolví checando el log de errores del servidor. Me faltaba añadir la extensión zip.so en el archivo php.ini, en la parte de Dynamic Extensions.

También les recomiendo usar PHPSpreadsheet en lugar de PHPExcel, ya que PHPExcel es una librería actualmente obsoleta.